# What Inequality holds true if and only if when $|x|+|y|+|z|+|x+y+z|=|x+y|+|y+z|+|z+x|$ is true?

Tags: inequality, summation, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

> What inequality holds true if and only if when
> $$|x|+|y|+|z|+|x+y+z|=|x+y|+|y+z|+|z+x|$$ is true?

Here, the variables $x,y,z$ are all real numbers.
I tried to find out the answer by dividing the cases:
when
$x\geq0, y\geq0, z\geq0$
$x\geq0, y\geq0, z\leq0$
and so on...
but can anyone simplify this procedure?

Comment: You can get some rather silly ones, such as:
$(|x|+|y|+|z|+|x+y+z|-|x+y|-|y+z|-|z+x|)^2\leq 0$

Answer (score 1):

After squaring of the both sides we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2+2|xy|+x^2+2xy+2|x(x+y+z))=\sum_{cyc}((x+y)^2+2|(x+y)(x+z)|)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(|xy|+|x^2+xy+xz|)=\sum_{cyc}|x^2+xy+xz+yz|.$$
But by the triangle inequality
$$|xy|+|x^2+xy+xz|\geq|xy+x^2+xy+xz+yz|=|(x+y)(x+z)|,$$ which says that it's enough to understand, when does the equality occur.

Can you end it now?